# how can i insert records of one table to another using trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 1 table as emp_demo and another table as emp_demos with same columns as

eg:

emp_demo_id|emp_demo_name

```
 1         |  xyz
```

i want to add AFTER INSERT trigger on emp_demo table so as soon as a record is inserted in emp_demo it should automatically get inserted into emp_demos table.

Comment: What type of table is `view_emp_demos`? If it's a tableview, it should automatically include the records of interest (rather than having to do this yourself and duplicate data)

Comment: no it is not a view table consider it as a user created table say emp_demos

Comment: I have achieved it through view table but wanted to know if I can do this using trigger

Comment: To answer your question yes you can..are you having a specific problem relating to an after insert trigger?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_trig
AFTER INSERT
ON emp_demo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO emp_demos(emp_demo_id, emp_demo_name)
VALUES(new.emp_demo_id, new.emp_demo_name);
END;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a96dae6409b8972199a738b2947a45b)

Comment: Hi, the demo is for oracle , the syntax is not the same for mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon, Updated the answer.